# ReceivedRemoteNotification and DidReceiveRemoteNotification never get called

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, appdelegate

We implemented remote push notifications in our app. What we would like to achieve is that when our app is in the background, a remote notification comes in, the user clicks on the notification, we perform some tasks based on the notification information. I noticed that when the app was in the background, when a notification came in, in Appdelegate, DidReceiveRemoteNotification and ReceivedRemoteNotification never get called. There's no way for me to get the notification from userInfo. Has anyone experienced this issue? Is this a bug? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Lichang

Comment: Are you using any third party service for push notifications like Appcenter, Firebase, or Azure Notification Hub?

Comment: I'm using pushsharp to send notifications

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are testing on a real device. You need to have this in your `info.plist`:

```xml
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
  <string>remote-notification</string>
</array>
```

and this in your `Entitlements.plist`:

```xml
<dict>
  <key>aps-environment</key>
  <string>development</string>
</dict>
```

Have your `AppDelegate` class implement this interface: `IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate`.

Try adding this and see if it gets called:

```cs
    [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, 
                           UNNotification notification, 
                           Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
    {
        completionHandler?.Invoke(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
    }

    public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, 
              NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
    {
        //BACKGROUND
        //handleNotification(userInfo);
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
    }
```

Also, on the apple developer portal, make sure that you either have added something for *Keys* or an *Apple Push Services* certificate and you have the cert in the provisioning profile that is signing the app.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I'll try that.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I did receive the remote notification when the app was in the background. The issue was that DidReceiveRemoteNotification didn't get triggered. That's why I couldn't get the notification info from userinfo.